# How to copy list and import as it is in postgresql database in fraction of a second

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm having an array list which has more than 1 million of records in it, I want to dump it as the way it is in PostgreSQL database using something built in methods like Copy-manger or any method which will be more faster to import this large amount of data in postgresql

My code is As follows

```
@Service
public class OrderProcessingService {
    
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    
    public void process_data(String hfrcode, List<Order> order) {
            
    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>(); 
  
    for(var data : order) {
    Order order_data = new Visit();
    order_data .setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    order_data .setOrderID(data.getOrderID());
    order_data .setOrderDate(data.getOrderDate());
    order_data .setWeight(data.getWeight());
    order_data .setOrderQuantity(data.getOrderQuantity());
    order_data .setOrderLocation(data.getOrderLocation());
    orderList.add(order_data );
    }

   orderRepository.saveAll(orderList);
 }
}
```

Instead of saving the list I want to copy it and dump it into PostgreSQL database so as I can minimize the execution time of importing the data into database.

Comment: Save the array in a single field in a table or with the array elements as separate fields?

Comment: Sory @AdrianKlaver can you provide more explanation on how I can save the array in a single field or with array elements as separate fields

Comment: 1) This is your decision not mine. 2) A 1 million element  array would probably run a foul of [Postgres lImits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html) for  a field. Also it would be hard to work with in the database. 3) [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) is expecting a file/file-like object that is either in TEXT or CSV format. You would need to present the data as detailed in the description for each at the link provided.